# Loop over array of hashes and perform titleize and return array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes that I want to iterate over and titleize an element of like so:

```
  @customer_activities.each do |activity|
    activity['name'].titleize
  end
```

how do I make sure the result of `activity['name'].titleize` ends up affecting the entries in `@customer_activities`?

Comment: `activity['name'] = activity['name'].titleize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@customer_activities.each do |activity|
    activity['name'] = activity['name'].titleize
end
```

Comment: Ideally there should had been something like `titleize!`, but unfortunately there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.map(&:titleize)` on the array.

`@customer_activities.map(&:titleize)` will return all elements of the array titleized.